# How to adjust for non-linear inverted-U relationship confounding variable?

Tags: data-transformation, splines, nonlinear, adjustment

In a multivariable regression model, if a potentially confounding variable has an inverted-U shape relationship with the outcome variable, what would be the best way to control for the confounding variable?

For my specific case, AGE is the confounding variable that has a highly non-linear relationship to the outcome, a disease.  The relationship between AGE and disease incident rate is an inverted U-shape.  Disease incidence rate starts low at young ages, rises to a sharp peak at a certain age, and then drops sharply for older ages, as seen in this image:

[image]

AGE is linearly correlated to the exposure of interest (a long internal half-life chemical) so will be a potential confounder.

Wouldn’t entering untransformed AGE into a logistic regression model or a linear regression model be inadequate for controlling its confounding effects?  Would entering a transformation of AGE be appropriate?  The only curves that fit well are splines or similar smoothing methods.  Can AGE be transformed with splines, entered in a regression model, and then appropriately control for confounding?

Are there other ways to control for a confounder that has an inverted U-shape relationship with the outcome?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using natural cubic spline? That would probably fit pretty well to the signal above. I would recommend it as long as you are OK with the shape of the actual response itself. You may find more reference here: http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/tmp/course.pdf#subsection.2.4.5